# Get map dimensions for map saved from map server

Tags: slam, navigation, map-saver, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After implementing SLAM using gmapping, the map was saved using map_server package, as a pgm file and a yaml file, I need to know the dimensions of the objects in the map and the map itself, how do I achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277519/get-map-dimensions-for-map-saved-from-map-server/) by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get the dimensions of the pgm (x pixels by y pixels) then examine your yaml file. In the yaml file the resolution of the map is given in meters/pixel. This will allow you to determine the size of your map in meters. You would figure out the size of objects in the map in a similar fashion (i.e., multiply the number of pixels your object takes by the resolution of your map and you'll have the physical size of the object).

Refer to http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fiorano10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29733/fiorano10/) on 2017-12-06**:
What are some ways I could get the x and y pixels for the map and not the pgm file? My pgm file has larger dimensions than the actual map.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-06**:
You can just manually edit the pgm so that it is the size of your map. I've used [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) to edit maps before.